# Load Failed error on a project (of multiple projects in a Solution), after Checking out a git branch from SourceTree

Tags: c#, git, checkout, atlassian-sourcetree, git-pull

I was trying to Checkout a remote branch (ModuleA) on Source-tree to my Local Repo. The checkout was successful, however one of the Projects of the Solution (the solution contains 17 projects in all) did not check out correctly. when I open the solution on my Visual Studio 2019, it shows the Project Load Failed. it is missing the `.csproj` file in the physical location. And when i try to Reload it says

> "Value Does not fall within the expected range"

I tried to use the Pull and Fetch options again, but no luck. Is there any way I can pull that particular project from the remote? Is there a workaround?
I have tried various suggestions mentioned online, but it mostly asks me to Delete branch and try again. And I am new to SourceTree (and clearly do not like it, for all the unclear messages it shows, without hinting on how to fix it), So please ignore my lack of knowhow on this.

Note: If it helps, I was earlier having issues with this Branch (ModuleA), with Commit and Push of some code i had done, which was not important and had tried to discard / Reset also. But in vain, so I had deleted the whole Branch. And now when I'm trying to start afresh by checking out the branch from remote, I have this issue. Also Note I had two other branches, which were also deleted.

Comment: Sounds like you got a few problems there with many variables.  Try building the solution from the command-line in the event Visual Studio is missing a certain project-type template.  If that fails then it may be because the source code wasn't added to Git in the first place.  Too little information to go on sadly

Comment: Thanks @MickyD for the response. I tried the Command line build and got the following error. 

"Build FAILED.

"D:\Projects\Project1Folder\MyProject\MyProject.sln" (MyProjectUIControls:Rebuild target) (1) ->
  D:\Projects\Project1Folder\MyProject\MyProject.sln.metaproj : error MSB4057: The target "MyProjectUIControls:Rebuild" does not exist in the project. [D:\Projects\Project1Folder\MyProject\MyProject.sln]"
-------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Also note: The source code was added in the Git and i was able to work fine before. the problems started after i created few branches to work on something irrelevant and then i started to discard those changes, which eventually led me to delete the entire branch. Let me know if you need any other details, to help with this further.